# Breadcrumbs Product hyperlink

Tags: magento-1.9, php, breadcrumbs

I need the breadcrumbs to hyperlink the current page i'm in..

For example

Home >> Category >> Product

usually, all parent categories hyperlinked. i wish to have product hyperlinked as well.

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Page
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Html page block
 *
 * @category   Mage
 * @package    Mage_Page
 * @author      Magento Core Team <core@magentocommerce.com>
 */
class Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    /**
     * Array of breadcrumbs
     *
     * array(
     *  [$index] => array(
     *                  ['label']
     *                  ['title']
     *                  ['link']
     *                  ['first']
     *                  ['last']
     *              )
     * )
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_crumbs = null;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->setTemplate('page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml');
    }

    function addCrumb($crumbName, $crumbInfo, $after = false)
    {
        $this->_prepareArray($crumbInfo, array('label', 'title', 'link', 'first', 'last', 'readonly'));
        if ((!isset($this->_crumbs[$crumbName])) || (!$this->_crumbs[$crumbName]['readonly'])) {
           $this->_crumbs[$crumbName] = $crumbInfo;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    protected function _toHtml() {             

   $cat_id = "";

   if (Mage::registry('current_product')) {
      $product_id = Mage::registry('current_product')->getId();
      $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
      $_product = $obj->load($product_id); // Enter your Product Id in $product_id

      if ($product_id) {
         $categoryIds = $_product->getCategoryIds();
         $cat_id = $categoryIds[0];
      }

      $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cat_id);
      $cat_name = $category->getName();
      $cat_url =  $this->getBaseUrl().$category->getUrlPath();
   }

   if (is_array($this->_crumbs)) {
      reset($this->_crumbs);
      $this->_crumbs[key($this->_crumbs)]['first'] = true;
      end($this->_crumbs);
      $this->_crumbs[key($this->_crumbs)]['last'] = true;
   }

   if($cat_id) {
      $this->_crumbs['category'.$cat_id] = array('label'=>$cat_name, 'title'=>'', 'link'=>$cat_url,'first'=>'','last'=>'','readonly'=>'');
      ksort($this->_crumbs);
      $home = $this->_crumbs['home'];
      unset($this->_crumbs['home']);
      array_unshift($this->_crumbs,$home);
   }

   $this->assign('crumbs', $this->_crumbs);
   return parent::_toHtml();
}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify getBreadcrumbPath() in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Data as links are not added to the breadcrumb array by default.

Do this with a rewrite that would look like

```
...
<helpers>
    <catalog>
        <rewrite>
            <data>[Vendor]_[ModuleName]_Helper_Catalog_Data</data>
        </rewrite>
    </catalog>
</helpers>
...
```

in your config.xml and the following would be the rewritten class

```
class [Vendor]_[ModuleName]_Helper_Catalog_Data extends Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data
{
    public function getBreadcrumbPath()
    {
        parent::getBreadcrumbPath();
        if (array_key_exists('product', $this->_categoryPath)) {
            $this->_categoryPath['product']['link'] = $this->getProduct()->getProductUrl();
        }

        return $this->_categoryPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Observe the proper event, perhaps something similar to (just guessing the event) `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`, (but perhaps something that would be less often observed) with a custom observer, similar to:

```
       <core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
            <observers>
                <df2k2_update_breadcrumb>
                    <class>df2k2_page/observer</class>
                    <method>updateBreadcrumbLink</method>
                </df2k2_update_breadcrumb>
            </observers>
        </core_block_abstract_to_html_before>
```

**Observer Class**

```
 public function updateBreadcrumbLink(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
 {

        $breadcrumbsBlock = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();

        if ($breadcrumbsBlock instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs) {
           // Get the block, get the last breadcrumb item in the array
           // and simply check for registry('current_product') or 'current_category',
           // and set the last item's  [`link`] element to either the product's url or the categories URL 
           // example,
          if (is_array($breadcrumbsBlock->_crumbs)) {
              end($breadcrumbsBlock->_crumbs);
              $breadcrumbsBlock->_crumbs[key($breadcrumbsBlock->_crumbs)]['link'] 
                  = Mage::getRegistry('current_product')->getUrl();
               // = Mage::helper('core')->getCurrentUrl();
          }
          $breadcrumbsBlock->assign('crumbs', $breadcrumbsBlock->_crumbs);

        }

        return $this;
  }
```

---

Once you set the `link` part for the last crumb item in the array of crumbs, then it will automatically render the item to include the linked URL.

There is a lot of detail missing with logic and object checking for current_product and category... Essentially, if there exists a registry for current_product, use that... if current_category, use that... otherwise, simply do whatever you want, or nothing at all.

If you don't wish to look up the details of the product/category.. just get the current URL and set the ['link'] element to the current URL.

---

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php if($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)): ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
  <ul>
    <?php foreach($crumbs as $_crumbName=>$_crumbInfo): ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $_crumbName ?>">
        <?php if($_crumbInfo['link']): ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></a>
        <?php elseif($_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
        <?php // i have add link code here as below ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $_crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['title']) ?>"><strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong></a>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_crumbInfo['label']) ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php if(!$_crumbInfo['last']): ?>
            <span>/ </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

edit above code in

```
app/design/frontend/[Your-theme]/[Your-package]/template/page/html/breadcrumbs.phtml
```

Comment: typo: breadcrums.phtml -- breadcrumbs.phtml, yes?

Comment: yes breadcrums.phtml